# Does $\mathbb E[X] < \infty$ imply that $\mathbb E[e^X] < \infty$?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $X$ be a non-negative random variable with finite expectation. Is this sufficient to say that $\mathbb E[e^X] < \infty$?

Jensen's equality clearly shows that if $\mathbb E[X] = \infty$ then also $\mathbb E[e^X] = \infty$, but is the converse true?

Comment: I should add that by Jensen inequality, you have the opposite inequality you would need to give your conclusion.

Comment: Use say density $\frac{2}{x^3}$ for $x\ge 1$. Then $\int_1^\infty e^x\cdot \frac{2}{x^3}\,dx$ diverges. Badly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No. We might have $P(X=n)=2^{-n}$. Then $\Bbb E[X]=2$ and $\Bbb E[e^X]=\sum_n 2^{-n}e^n=\infty$